# Java form from xml

Tags: java, xml, swing

is there a tool to generate a Swing form from xml code?

Comment: What do you mean by a "Swing form"?

Comment: @Gnoupi: A Swing JFrame with the appropriate objects on it as a reasonable guess.

Comment: @omg - hmm, i didn't know there were many such frameworks, actually. I mean outside of what Matisse does, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of frameworks can be found at [java-source](http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-user-interface-toolkits). Out of these [SWIXML](http://www.swixml.org/) seems most popular. Additionally I found [CookSwing](http://cookxml.yuanheng.org/cookswing/) and [JFCML](http://jfcml.sourceforge.net/). I have no experience with either of them, so I cannot recommend one above the other.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.metawidget.org/

Answer (score 0):

You may use some of xml-to-javabeans frameworks (like JAXB) plus some of javabeans-to-swing forms frameworks (like http://www.metawidget.org/ or http://code.google.com/p/swing-formbuilder/)